# How to transfer bool index array to integer index array in cuda?

Tags: arrays, indexing, cuda

I have problem in transfering a bool index array to integer one with cuda. Here is an example. I found I could use some thrust function to do this, since I don't know exactly. But I would like to know could I do it in a kernel function? I think this step could be paralleled by cuda.

```
bool idxA = {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1};// the bool index
int idxB = ｛2,5,6,8｝; // the integer index
```

I think the kernel should be like below, but I could not complete it.

```
__global__ void transfer(int ni1, const bool* idx1, int ni2, int * idx2)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  if (i<ni1)
    if(idx1[i])
      idx2[index] = i;// I don't know how to write this index
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. You have two choices:

1. Just do `idx2[i] = i;`, which will leave gaps in the output which can be removed afterwards by [stream compaction](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction_ga50e1ff3b382ad6d65c0f69dc01c4832e.html#ga50e1ff3b382ad6d65c0f69dc01c4832e).
2. Use an [atomically incremented global counter](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd) to index the array.

The first option is probably preferable if the output is very dense (few false values in the boolean array). The second option is probably better if the output is very sparse (few true values in the boolean array). This would look something like:

```
__device__ int index; // zero this before launching kernel

__global__ void transfer(int ni1, const bool* idx1, int ni2, int * idx2)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  if (i<ni1)
    if(idx1[i])
      int j = atomicAdd(&index, 1);
      idx2[j] = i;
}
```

Which you choose probably depends on your problem size, sparsity and target hardware.

Comment: Could I know more about the stream compaction? If I could not use the thrust/remove function.

Comment: You are free to search for "cuda stream compaction" and read what you find